# Difference between shortcut reverse and url reverse in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am learning django. And recently I have came upon something that I don't understand.

There are two different version of reverse module that can be imported.

One is:

`from django.shortcuts import reverse`

Another is:

`from django.urls import reverse`

What are the actual difference between them? Can someone explain to me in an easy way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no difference they put it to packages, the original is in urls but because it use so much it is on shortcuts too, think of it like windows shortcuts and original file